# Using CocoaPods with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm new to Cocoapods and am trying to use a pod named [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools) in my OS X app Swift project.

I installed Cocoapods, created the podfile, added `pod 'DateTools'` to it, ran `pod install` and everything seemed to work fine. (I'm a Ruby dev so I think I got this part right).

As asked by Cocoapods, I now opened my project using the new `.xcworkspace` file created. I correctly see two projects in Xcode: mine and `Pods`.

I added a sample model file to my project, let's call it `SampleModel` but in the code, when I do this:

```
let date = NSDate()
var year = date.year
```

I get the error: `'NSDate' does not have a member named 'year'`. According to DateTools [README](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools/blob/master/README.md), this *should* work.

As I'm new to both Xcode and Cocoapods, I can't figure out what is the likely error: DateTools not working with Swift or did I fail to import something, somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import module into your source file

```
import DateTools
```

Also, by default is CocoaPods building static libraries - to use those you would need to configure bridging header. Easier way is to make it build dynamic framework by specifying so in `Podfile` (and run `pod install`):

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'DateTools'
```