# How to get swift based code in Xcode to see Cocoapod's pods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, fmdb, cocoalumberjack

I have installed Cocoapods with FMDB, CocoaLumberjack and FBSDKCoreKit as pods, but I am not able to get access to them in my code. I am sure there is some simple fix but as it stands I am unable to find them,.. wondering if someone can point me in the right direction?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850261/add-cocoapods-to-tests-target-too/17850444#17850444) but still am having the same issue.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078573/using-cocoapods-with-swift/30079369#30079369. Btw both "this" in your question link to the same page.